# How to add parts of a text file without using pandas?

Tags: python

I have a txt file with 3 elements that I have opened in python and creates the following output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrSLo.png)

If the second item in each list is the same, I need to add the 3rd output. For example, for all the lists where the second item is '23', I want to add the third item together i.e:1+1+2+1=5.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: what about first element?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are printing out the lists via a loop, you can check the 2nd value of each list in the loop and add the 3rd value to a variable.

EDIT: changing the code to allocate different sums for different values using a dictionary.

```
totalSum = {}
for i in lists:
    # print list
    if i[1] in totalSum.keys(): 
        totalSum[i[1]] = totalSum.get(i[1]) + i[2]
    else:
        totalSum[i[1]] = i[2]
```

Comment: May I know how to do it without specifying 23? I'll have to repeat the same process with many other txt files as well.

Comment: So what value are you looking for?

Comment: Do you want separate sums for different numbers?

Comment: Yes, I want separate sums for different numbers. However, I want to do it without specifying the number repeatedly.

Comment: @Santhi I edited the code to do as you asked.